# getView ListView selected item color change

Tags: java, android, listview, getview

I am looking to set the selected item in `getView()`, is working however every item in my list is selected. I have tested with toasts and the correct is displayed so the condition is working. The condition checks to see if an entry from a DB for the specific item is set to true (thus being selected).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(isItemSelected.equals("true")){
          listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAFFFF);
     }
     else if (isItemSelected.equals("false")){
     // Default color    
     }
}
```

Comment: did u write  listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(non selected color); in else part

Comment: you want to highlight a particular cell ? if so then you can also set background of your layout of a cell something like this         linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(COLOR.GREY);

Comment: Please post the whole code in getView() --- check if you are recycling the views in list because if you are then the selected item when recycled will already be selected !! if thats whats happening !!

Comment: listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("FF00FF"));

Comment: i am not showing a cell selected in get view rather i am showing a list with data and at even places grey color and odd places white color by making my linear layout background color grey and white respectively. shall i post the code ?

Comment: Have the else to another color, that color will then be used for all items! strange, but I guess listview is reusing that color regardless of the condition.
However, when I used listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF00); and set true and false to different color codes it stays white but changes when I quickly scroll up and down, then goes back to white again.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your background colors every conditions like below;

```
 listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(isItemSelected.equals("true") ? selectedColor : unSelectedColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make these changes in your code hope it works out.

```
   @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        if (convertView == null) {    
        if (isItemSelected.equals("true")){
listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAFFFF);
          }
          else if (isItemSelected.equals("false")){
            // Default color    
          }
            }else{

         if (isItemSelected.equals("true")){

    listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAFFFF);
           }
          else if (isItemSelected.equals("false")){
             // Default color    
          } 
        }
```

please try this

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution for your requirement,

Paste this code in your view file

```
SparseBooleanArray singleChecked;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (position != singleListSelectedPosition) {
            singleListSelectedPosition = position;
            int totalCount = lvSingleSelect.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    boolean stat = singleChecked.get(position, false);
                    singleChecked.put(position, !stat);
                } else {
                    singleChecked.put(i, true);
                }
            }
             adapter.setChecked(singleChecked);
        }
    }
```

And this is your adapter class code:

```
public void setChecked(SparseBooleanArray ch) {
        singleChecked = ch;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (singleChecked.get(position, false)) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.titlebar_background_color));
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(
                    getResources().getColor(R.color.emphasis_color));
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any trouble with this, always happy to help.

Comment: Are the same issue you getting still??, let me know what the issue you are getting with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding an extra value like boolean while adding data in your arraylist. true for selected and false for not selected. Initially add false with all. And then when you click on listviewTitles

```
int positionClicked;

listviewTitles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           for (int i = 0; i < bean_List.size(); i++) {
           if (i == position) {
                positionClicked = position;
                bean_List.get(position).setIsClicked(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Do your task here...
           } else {
                bean_List.get(i).setIsClicked(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
     }
});
```

And in getView() use this:-

```
    if (bean_List.get(position).getIsClicked() == true) {
        listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAFFFF);
        //change color accordingly
    } else {
        listviewTitles.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAAFFFF);
        //change color accordingly
    }
```